# How to connect docker's container with pipeline

Tags: docker, containers, pipeline

I would like to have custom server which listens inside docker's container (e.g on TCP 192.168.0.1:4000). How to send data in and out from outside of the container. I don't want to use host ports for bridging. I would rather use pipelines or something which not take host network resources. Please show me full example of docker command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

You start your container as

```
docker run -v /host/path:/container/path ...
```

and then you can pipe data to files in `/host/path` and they will be visible in `/container/path` and vise versa.

Comment: I suppose by "pipe data" you probably mean the deposit of data files.  I wonder, though if a  [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) created with `mkfifo` would also work between the host and a container in a directory shared with`-v` ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your server's clients are docker containers as well you don't need to expose any host ports:

```
docker run --name s1 -d -p 3000 myserver

docker run -d --link s1:serverName client
```

Now you can reach your server from the client container at `serverName:3000`.

**UPDATE:** I just saw that you want to be able to send data from outside any containers. You can still use the same approach, depending on your use case/data volume. Every time you want to send data, create a container that sends it. Using the cli it might look like:

```
echo "Lots of data" | docker run --rm --link s1:serverName client
```

Client would have to read from stdin and send the data to `serverName:3000`. After it's finished it will be automatically removed.

Comment: I am newbie with docker but this is what i need: I know how to run container on this way:

docker run -d -p 192.168.0.3:2000:514/udp -v /var/log/syslog-ng:/var/log/syslog-ng --name syslog-ng bobrik/syslog-ng

My question is can i use some sort of pipe, or something what not take network resource, instead "192.168.0.3:2000" to communicate with container. Something like this:

docker run -d -p my_pipe:514/udp -v /var/log/syslog-ng:/var/log/syslog-ng --name syslog-ng bobrik/syslog-ng

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're asking for makes sense. Let's say you use a UNIX pipe to capture standard output from a docker container.

```
$ docker run --rm -t busybox dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 > junk
$ du -hs junk
4.0K    junk
```

If your docker client is connected to the docker host via tcp, of course that traffic uses the hosts's networking stack. It uses a method called [hijacking](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.14/#32-hijacking) to transport data on the same socket as the http-ish connection between the client and host.

If your docker client is connected to the host via a unix socket, then your client is on the host, and that pipeline is not using the tcp stack. But you still can't transport that data off the host without using the host's networking.

So using the networking stack is unavoidable if you want to get data from the host. That said, if your criteria is just to avoid allocating additional ports, pipelines do allow you to use the original docker host socket instead of creating new ports. But pipelines aren't the same as a tcp socket, so your application needs to be designed to understand standard input and output.

One approach that grants you access to an already-created container's internally-exposed ports is the [ambassador](http://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) container-linking pattern.